# TypeError: detect_vcs() missing 1 required positional argument: 'ui' when running `devpi upload --formats bdist_wheel`

Tags: python, devpi

```
username@machinename:~/$ devpi upload --formats bdist_wheel
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/python3.6/bin/devpi", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/opt/python3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/devpi/main.py", line 32, in main
    return method(hub, hub.args)
  File "/opt/python3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/devpi/upload.py", line 33, in main
    setupdir_only=setupcfg.get("setupdir-only"))
  File "/opt/python3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/devpi/upload.py", line 281, in __init__
    hasvcs = check_manifest.detect_vcs().metadata_name
TypeError: detect_vcs() missing 1 required positional argument: 'ui'
```

My versions are:

```
devpi-client==5.1.0
devpi-common==3.4.0
```

How can I solve this? I tried upgrading/downgrading `devpi-client` to `4.4.0` and to `5.1.1` but it still gives me the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to an incompatibility between the 2 packages `check_manifest` and `devpi`. Since `check_manifest==0.42`, the `detect_vcs` function takes a required argument `ui` and `devpi` does not give it in the version you have (`hasvcs = check_manifest.detect_vcs().metadata_name`)

There are 2 solutions to this problem:

1. Downgrade `check_manifest` to `0.41`.
2. Upgrade devpi-client to a version >= 5.2.0. (since the fix has been introduced for `devpi-client==5.2.0` (https://github.com/devpi/devpi/commit/f40e0f51b610325d807367206cced90ed1fa005d)